# How to switch to netcat-traditional in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, netcat

How do I switch to `netcat-traditional` in Ubuntu? Whenever I write `netcat -h`, it appears that I am running `netcat-openbsd` instead.

I'm new to Ubuntu, so exact commands would be helpful.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

1. enable universe repository (if not enabled)

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository universe
   ```
2. Install the other netcat using synaptic. (To do this, the universe repository must be enabled.)

   ```
   sudo apt-get install netcat-traditional
   ```
3. type `sudo update-alternatives --config nc`
4. Select the option `/bin/nc.traditional`
5. type `nc -h`

output:

```
[v1.10-38]
connect to somewhere:   nc [-options] hostname port[s] [ports] ...
listen for inbound: nc -l -p port [-options] [hostname] [port]
options:
    -c shell commands   as `-e'; use /bin/sh to exec [dangerous!!]
    -e filename     program to exec after connect [dangerous!!]
...
```

Comment: Note: step 1  `sudo apt-get install netcat`